# Modal Body content float to Modal footer area and occupy footer are

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, bootstrap-datepicker

[Madal Body content appear at modal footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbQfD.png)

- I have faced one problem in which the content of modal body appear at modal footer
- whatever i write within modal body it will float to the modal footer

```html
<html>
  <head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap-select.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
<div class="row" id="aap_modals">
 <div class="col-md-12" >
      <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true" >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Select Question Heading</i></button>
 </div>
 <!-- Modal HTML -->
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" data-keyboard="false"     data-backdrop="static">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
     <h4 class="modal-title">Select Question</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
   <div class="col-xs-2">
     <label for="ex1">col-xs-2 and this is the problem </label>
    <input class="form-control" id="ex1" type="text">
   </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: set your style .col-xs-2{float:none}; no height there bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a row inside modal body, Replace that modal body with this snip,

```
     <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-2">
                  <label for="ex1">col-xs-2 and this is the problem </label>
                  <input class="form-control" id="ex1" type="text">
             </div> 
         </div>
      </div>
```